# laravel/framework[v10.0.0, ..., v10.0.3] require composer-runtime-api ^2.2 -> found composer-runtime-api[2.1.0] but it does not match the constraint

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-10

When trying to install laravel 10, I am getting this error-

> laravel/framework[v10.0.0, ..., v10.0.3] require composer-runtime-api
> ^2.2 -> found composer-runtime-api[2.1.0] but it does not match the
> constraint.

Comment: And what's your question about this? Sounds like you are running a pretty outdated version of Composer

Answer (score 107, accepted):

To solve the problem, I had to update the composer by running the commands-

`composer clearcache`

`composer selfupdate`

Comment: also, it's good to use laravel sail.

Answer (score 11):

To resolve this problem, you can simply update your composer by running the following command:

```
composer self-update
```

After updating, try again and this should resolve your issue

Answer (score 5):

Use `sudo composer self-update` For some reason composer -v was showing 2.5.8 so composer self-update was by itself not updating the global version. Using sudo updated the 'hidden' version that was using the older runtime.